# Can I edit my app code after its been reviewed and accepted in the app store?

Tags: ios

I just uploaded my app, And i need to update my banking and info,

But I also need to fix the code inside the app for in app-purchases:

Will i be able to access and change the relevant information once the app is in the store?

My first time!

Comment: No. You will need to increment your version number (i.e. 1.0.1) and generate a new binary that must be submitted for review and approved before your code adjustments will take effect in the store. You may not modify a binary that has been reviewed and approved.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your banking and account info.  You cannot update your app, it will have to go through review again.  Also when you add in app purchases for the first time you must submit the at the same time as your submit a new version of the app.

Comment: Also it's pretty common for someone to submit 1.0 of an app to the app store and during the 1-2 week approval process work on features and bug fixes for version 1.1.  As soon as version 1 is approved and released then they will submit 1.1 for review.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change code once it is uploaded to app store. But you can reject your binary or can fix in next version of app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can not change the source code of an already live version of your application.
What you're able to change are some metadata information about your current live version. Please refer to the following link, which explains what you're able to change [Changing live apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH3-SW46).
What you could do is to provide a new version of your application with the source code fixes that you need to add. Use the following guide to do that: [Replacing your app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html)
Hope this helps!.